# Creating a merged coastal terrain model using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, bathymetry

I have a bathymetric data set (Float32) and a standard DEM (Int16). I'm struggling to merge them using "*Raster>Merge*". I've set "nodata" to -9999 using "*conversion>translate*" this displays the DEM nodata as -3.40282e+35. The final merge retains nodata of one dataset depending on input order rather than selecting the z data from both sets. How can I merge the two.

I need to be able to run a number of sea level height models with changing uplift.